# Django admin multiple photo upload

Tags: django, file-upload, admin

I have to create a blog posting system and I need to make it possible to upload multiple photos in Django Admin and select it via Django TinyMCE. One of the solutions is Filebrowser, but I have already spent a few days and haven't got it worked. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to do something similar, but not with Tinymce, I choose [wmd](https://github.com/jpartogi/django-wmd-editor).
I created two models, one for the blog post, and one for the images, and in the admin interface I included the images as inlines. here's some example.

in your model.py file:

```
class Project(models.Model):
  ...
  #TinyMce field.
  description = models.TextField()  

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='prjimages/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/')
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

than in your admin.py file, you can have the PostImage as inline.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *

class ProjectImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass

class ProjectImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = ProjectImage
  max_num=10
  extra=0

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ProjectImageInline,]

admin.site.register(ProjectImage, ProjectImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

you can change the ImageField Widget to show the url, and maybe a preview for each image (I have no example code for this at the moment). And if the user want to include the image in the post, he can just copy paste the url to Tinymce.

It's not a complete solution, but maybe you can extend it with some work to fit your needs.

Comment: I meant those ## ** and so on remains.

Comment: I don't understand your comments, I find no relation to the answer I gave you. What are you talking about? I would really like to help you, but I'm not sitting in front of your computer, explain your problems in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should take look at Dropzone.js which you can easily drag and drop multiple images to admin page.